# Creating Random Unlabelled Graphs

Tags: graphs

Hi I am using exam class and I am trying to make random graphs for a multiple choice question as shown. Would appreciate it if the graphs can be aligned horizontally as A and B, C and D[image: multiple choice graphs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begingroup\renewcommand\labelenumi{\Alph{enumi}.}%
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={baseline=2.1cm,
execute at begin picture={%
\draw[-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (2,0) node[above right]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,2.5) node[below left]{$y$};}}}%
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-0.5,-1) -- (2,1.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \item \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-1,2) parabola bend (0,0) (1,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \item \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \item \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-1,0.2) to[out=0,in=-150] (1.5,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about your book on "How to properly hibernate"? I don't know how to hibernate.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer The first step is to build a burrow. Do you have a burrow?

Comment: I need the book that you said in your profile. Where is the book?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer It is not finished yet.

Comment: If you continue offering bounties, you can be the winner in the following competition: [the top bounty investors](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors).